# Train NN with time series?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As far as I understand Keras NN shuffles the data during training.

How do you train NN with time series data where input and output data has to be in sync during training i.e. train at the same sequence as the data is ordered ? (Normal NN, not LSTM or something).

Comment: What do you mean by "in sync"? At the end of each epoch both training data and labels are shuffled; however the same shuffling is applied on both training data and the labels so their correspondence is preserved. Further, you can turn this off by passing `shuffle=False` to `fit` method.

Comment: And please don't ask multiple different questions in a single question post. Ask them separately in different question posts.

Comment: If it's not an RNN, why would the data have to be in sync?